# Derrangments function for coloring a chess table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to color a chess table of size n*n with n different colors. We color in such a way that in each horizontal row there are all colors and at the same time in no vertical row there are two fields of the same color next to each other. I think we can use derangements for this but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fill in the first row any way you like.  How many options?  Now, you are correct, the second row has to be a derangement of the first.  How many options there?  Each row in turn is a derangement of the one above.

Comment: So for the first row I think there are n^n ways we can color the first row. So for the second row there are D(n^n) ways to color it? But how do I continue this?

Comment: No, you need one of each color in the first row, so there are fewer. How many?

Comment: There is n^n * n^(n-1) * n^(n-2) * n^(n-3) ... n^1.

Comment: The first row has $n$ objects that you can put in any order, so there are $n!$ ways to do it.

Comment: Then the second row has D(n!) ways to do it. The third D(D(n!)) etc..?

Comment: No, the second row has $D(n)$ ways to do it.  You have $n$ objects to put in order with every one moving from its place in the first row.

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding for so long. Does this mean that all of them after the first one have D(n) ways to arrange them? Or is it D(n)+D(n-1)...D(1)?

Comment: Yes, each row after the first is $D(n)$.  In one row you have an order of the $n$ squares.  The restriction on two together vertically says you have to make the order for the next row such that every color is moved to a new location.  That is the definition of a derangement.

Comment: So, the solution altogether is n!*(n-1)*Dn?

Comment: No, it is $n!(D(n))^{n-1}$ because you have $n-1$ rows that are a derangement of the one above.  You need to work on the multiplication principle.

Comment: Thanks you a lot.